# paypal IOS sdk login failure

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk

i created an IOS app using the new paypal IOS sdk. i have a test account set up with paypal, and i am playing in the sandbox.
i get the paypal login screen, but that is where i am a bit stuck.
i am trying to use an actual paypal account to log in with, and after trying to validate it, the email and password fields "wiggle", and then stop. i am still faced with the login screen, and it doesn't log me in.
i know the sandbox is working, since i can use the credit card portion perfectly.
my question therefore is:
do i need a special second sandbox account to test with instead of a "real" paypal account?
that is the only thing i can think of. does this makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

Yes your guess is right. You need to create sandbox test account to test it in a sandbox box.
You can not use your real account in sandbox mode.

You can do it from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts).

Comment: i am using sandbox accounts, even though i am getting failure message.